# VSTS + Octopus Deploy? Why do I see a lot of CI/CD setups with both?

Tags: azure-devops, octopus-deploy

I'm a developer whose transitioning into Devops.  By observation, I've noticed that a lot of dev shops have started using Octopus Deploy and Azure Devops Services (AzDo, formerly VSTS), or they are starting new projects to setup devops ci/cd pipelines AND they spec to use both tools.

I've been through some quick training for both tools and though they aren't perfectly the same, AzDo seems to offer all of the same features as Octopus Deploy.

So, my question is if a company is already using AzDo for much of their version control, or anything CI/CD pipeline-related, why would you use Octopus?  What benefit does it offer to use Octopus for your build and deploys to AzDo?

Note, I am very, very new to Devops.  I'm just asking because at the "10,000 feet view" there doesn't seem to be any reason for Octopus if you're already using AzDo.  I mention Octopus Deploy by name because I see it come up frequently.  However, I assume there could be other tools that serve the same purpose of automatic build and deploying that might also integrate with AzDo.  However, AzDo offers build and deploy built in one.  Why split out the work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me preface why I like to both build and deploy with VSTS:

- Same permissioning end to end
- Line of sight from end to end build and deployment

Reasons I favor Octopus Deploy over VSTS Release:

- **Ability to upload packages/artifacts**

  - External ones that are maybe one off packages to get deployed for a specific release
- **Target Definition**

  - When you create Targets or servers you are deploying to, you are able to add a target to one or multiple environments and assign tags/roles to a target. What does this mean? More flexible server definition rather than defining strict Agents to a pool or servers to a Deployment Group, you can allow a target to span multiple (ie: a testing server that spans your Dev and Test environments and only gets triggered on steps that are defined for that role).  I realize you can accomplish *similar* things to this in VSTS but in my opinion it's far more cumbersome.
- **Variable Definition**

  - Variables can be grouped at a global level and grouped by a specific pipeline/process  (that part is similar to VSTS). Variables can also be grouped or `scoped` by environments or roles (above) so you are able to have different variable values per role per environment; both super granular and flexible.  Places this comes in handy is if you have a backend server with a connection string and maybe 2 content delivery nodes (role - `content delivery`) that get slightly *different* values than the backend server.  At the moment, I do not know (other than creating new environments) how one would accomplish the same in VSTS.
- **Process Definition**

  - All of the above comes together in the process definition of Octopus Deploy.  The super flexible and granular variables and target definition allows you to focus on the *actual* deployment process rather than getting hung up on the nuances of the UI and its limitations.  One example would be defining a process where the first step would be taking something out of a load balancer from a central server, step two deploy code to delivery server one, step three put back in lb, step 4 take out node two from lb called from a central server, step 5 deploy code to node two, and last step, back into load balancer. I realize it's a very simple hypothetical, but within Octopus Deploy, it's one steady process filtered to execute on specific roles, within VSTS you would have to break that down into different agent phases and probably pipelines.

Above are really the biggest points I see to use Octopus Deploy over VSTS Release.  Now why would someone use VSTS to build and OD to release/deploy? There are a lot of different factors that go into it, some are corporate drivers like having an enterprise git client that has permissions handled thru MSDN. Sometimes it's a project management driver of having work items tied tightly to commit and builds, but with the added flexibility that OD brings to the table for free/minimal cost.

Hoping this help shine a little light into maybe why some people are crossing streams and using both VSTS and OD.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of good points have been made already, but it really comes down to what you need. I would venture a lot of us started using Octopus before Release Management was really a thing.

We use VSTS for all our source control and builds and then all our deployments are handled through Octopus.

When we started evaluating tools, VSTS had nothing for deployments. Even now, they are still playing catch up to Octopus in feature set.

If you are doing true multi-tenanted and multi-environment deployments, I don't think VSTS really compares. We are using Octopus with around 30 tenants, some on Azure, some on premise. We deploy a mix of web and desktop apps. We are even using Octopus to deploy some legacy VB6 and winforms applications.

- **Multi-Tenancy** (critical for us)

  - VSTS added Deployment Groups a while ago which sound pretty similar to Octopus Environments before multi-tenancy was implemented. Before Octopus had true multi-tenancy (it's been around a while now), people would work around it by creating different environments per tenant, like "CustomerA - Dev", "CustomerA - Prod", etc. Now you just have your Dev/Test/Prod environments and each tenant can have variables scoped to those individual environments.
- **Support**

  - Documentation is excellent and it's really easy to get up and running.
  - The few times I've needed to contact someone at Octopus, they've answered very quickly and knowledgeably.
- **Usability**

  - Having the Octopus dashboard giving us an overview of all our projects is amazing. I don't know of anyway to do this in VSTS, without going into each individual project.
  - Octopus works great on a mobile device for checking deployment status and even starting new deployments.
- **Community**

  - Octopus works with their customers to understand what they want and they often release draft RFCs and have several times completely changed course based on customer feedback.

If we know what sort of applications you are deploying, and to what kinds of environments, we would be able to better tailor our responses.

Answer (score 1):

The features you see today in VSTS weren't there a few years ago, so there might be an historical reason.
But I want to state here some non-opinionated reasons that may suggest an organization to opt for different tools instead of one.

- Separate responsibility and access levels
- Multiple CI tools in dev teams (orgs that are using also Jenkins or TeamCity or else) and need to standardize and control deployments
- An org needs a feature available only in Octopus (maybe Multi-tenancy)

Answer (score 1):

Octopus does a great job of focusing on deployments. Features reach octopus before vsts, support is local and responsive. That, and you never run out of build/release minutes!

Seriously though, I just like to support smaller companies where possible and if all features were equal, I'd still pick them.

Answer (score 0):

The big reason in the past was that TFS On prem and early VSTS did NOT support non-Microsoft (.Net) code very well if at all. You could utilize the source control and work features of TFS and then use octopus/Jenkins etc... as the build release parts to cover code that TFS didn't really know what to do with.

Also the release pipelines used to be very simplistic and not that useful where the other products were all plugin based and could do (almost) anything you needed them to. Most of that has changed so that VSTS is much better at working with Non-Microsoft code bases then it used to be. Over time integrations get created inside a companies walls and undoing those decisions can be more painful then just having "too many" tools. Also I feel like there is just more people out there familiar with those tools since they have been mature longer and cover a larger part of the development world then VSTS has in the past.

Answer (score 0):

To fully implement CD you need both. VSTS runs tests and is a build server. OD isn’t. VSTS is light on sophisticated application installations. And if you are provisioning environments, IaC style, you need Terraform in addition. Don’t try to shoehorn everything into a single tool. DevOps requires a whole ecosystem.   The reasons are not historical.