# Octopus deploy migration to Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, octopus-deploy

Looking for step-by-step guide or best practices on how to migrate from Octopus deploy to Azure pipeline. Similar to the documentation Microsoft has on Travis migration to Azure pipelines.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding this issue,as far as I know, there is no clear document to introduce the migration from Octopus to azure pipeline. The existing documents are all about two technologies work together as part of a pipeline:[Octopus Integration with Azure DevOps](https://octopus.com/blog/azure-devops-extension-v4). The reason why the two need to work together is because they have their own advantages, you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446205/vsts-octopus-deploy-why-do-i-see-a-lot-of-ci-cd-setups-with-both) about this.

If you decide to deprecate Octopus and only use azure devops,then I think you can first understand how to use pipeline to deploy through the official documentation. Here are some document you can refer to :

- [Azure Pipelines documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops)
- [Release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops)
- [Deploy applications using Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/learn/paths/deploy-applications-with-azure-devops/)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out and for the documentation links. Yes the initial plan is to deprecate Octopus, our first step is to create a pipeline design in Azure and understand what steps can be directly translated and what steps need more work. You links will help!!!